# VBA: Prevent Autocomplete in combobox while

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I currently have a userform that has a combobox and a listbox. Both contain the same list of items (the combobox has an extra null value). If a user selects an item in the combobox, then the same item will be selected in the list box.

The problem that I am having is coming from the combobox autocompleting when the user tries typing a value instead of choosing one from the combobox. When the user types a value, it will autocomplete what they typed to a value within the combobox. (If I type "8" then the combobox will autocomplete that to "8184123".)

If I set MatchEntry to 2 - fmMatchEntryNone, then the combobox does not autocomplete. However, the combobox does not select a value based on what the user has typed.

Is there any way to stop the combobox from autocompleting while keeping letting MatchEntry stay at 1 - fmMatchEntryComplete? Or is there anyway to implement fmMatchEntryComplete only when the value that the user enters is exactly equal to a value in the list of the combobox?

Answer (score 2):

you can have ComboBox methods and properties work for you

in the form calling sub place:

```
Sub main()

        ' code that preceeeds the userform loading...

       With UserForm1

           'other code to set some userform or userform controls properties...

           .ComboBox1.MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone ' <--| set this just before showing userform
           .Show
       End With

       Unload UserForm1

        ' code that follows the userform closing...


End Sub
```

in the userform code pane place this function:

```
Function CheckCB(cboBox As MSForms.ComboBox) As Boolean
    With cboBox
        .Text = .Value '<-- This is the "trick": "refresh" the combobox text
        CheckCB = .MatchFound
        If Not CheckCB Then
            MsgBox "Invalid entry", vbCritical
            .SetFocus
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

despite [MSDN online doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264834.aspx) the refreshing of `.Value` actually has `MatchEntry` and `MatchRequired` work on it even if `MatchEntry` is set to `fmMatchEntryNone`

then you have to call `CheckCB()` function to prevent leaving userform until your combobox has been entered a valid value

for instance you could place it in any "exit" button `click` event handler

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Not CheckCB( ComboBox1 ) Then Exit Sub '<-- if ComboBox check failed then exit

    ' otherwise let code run ...

End Sub
```

or, if you wanted the user not to enter any other control until your combobox  has a valid value, you must act similarly for every other userform control event handler, i.e. placing `If Not CheckCB Then Exit Sub` at their beginning

Comment: Sorry about the edit.  I missed something when I read it on my phone.

Comment: I approved it. You just make sure it works! otherwise get it back

Comment: @Thomas Inzina I approved it. You just make sure it works! otherwise get it back

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Form1.ComboBox1.AutoWordSelect = True`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

### Custom Autocomplete

Turn off match entry

> ComboBox1.MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone

When the user types iterate over the combo's list.  It there is only 1 possible match, select it.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, matchIndex As Integer
    matchIndex = -1
    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        If InStr(1, ComboBox1.List(i), ComboBox1.Value) Then
            If matchIndex = -1 Then
                matchIndex = i
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If matchIndex > -1 Then ComboBox1.ListIndex = matchIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I changed one line of code and got it to work. I changed "If Instr(1, ComboBox1.List(i), ComboBox1.Value) Then" to "If StrComp(ComboBox1.List(i), ComboBox1.Value) = 0 Then"